# printf() in c. Should it not treat the input value as an address

Tags: c, printf

I just saw the signature for `printf`. it is `int printf(const *f)`. Now, if I declare an `int i` and do the following:

```
int i=5;
printf("%d",i);
```

it displays the correct value of `i`. I am wondering why is is this so. Since `printf` accepts a pointer, should it not treat the value of `i` as an address and print the value stored at that address.

Note that `printf("%d", &i)` does not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only parameter required by printf is a format string, which must be convertible to a const char*. That doesn't mean that other parameters must be pointers. printf doesn't really know about the other parameters except by looking at the format string. It parses the format string looking for patterns that start with %. In your case it sees %d and says "there should be a int parameter on the stack", so it goes out and grabs the next parameter and interprets it as an int. If you don't provide a matching parameter or provide a parameter of the wrong type, it will print garbage.

Comment: thanks for you help! can you please provide an explanation for scanf() also. if I do scanf("%d", i), what does it really mean. %d what does it tell scan

Comment: scanf works the same way except that it always requires a pointer so that it can modify its target, i.e. if you specify %d to scanf it needs a pointer to int.

Answer (score 4):

[`printf()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/printf) is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D). That means that its first argument indicates the number and type of remaining arguments to be pulled from the stack.

The first argument - and the only one that is not affected by the function being variadic - is a *string* and therefore a pointer (to an array of `char`, if it matters). The remaining arguments are processed differently and are not listed in the simplistic prototype that you mentioned.

BTW, here's the full prototype of `printf()` as pulled from my `stdio.h` header:

```
extern int printf (const char *format, ...);
```

Comment: thanks for you help! can you please provide an explanation for scanf() also. if I do scanf("%d", i), what does it really mean. %d what does it tell scanf

Answer (score 1):

The first argument is a format string. When you pass a string to a function, you're essentially passing a pointer.

(Also, the signature is actually `int printf(const char *, ...)`.)

Answer (score 0):

[`printf(3)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/sprintf.3.html) is a [variadic function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variadic_function#Variadic_functions_in_C.2C_Objective-C.2C_C.2B.2B.2C_and_D). It interprets its *additional* arguments from the *format string*.

Answer (score 0):

No - printf just gets a 32bit (or whatever) value, it has no idea what type you think that it is.

Answer (score 0):

The signature of `printf` is NOT `int printf(const *f)`. Where did you get that strange signature?

The real signature of `printf` is `int printf(const char *, ...)` . Note the `...` at the end. That `...` stands for variadic arguments that you pass to `printf` after the first argument. The first argument is the format (`"%d"` in your case). The other arguments are interpreted by `printf` in accordance with that format. You specified `%d` as the format, which means that the next argument is interpreted as an `int` value, not as an address.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add that `printf("%d", &i)` is indeed working. 
Instead of printing the value of the i variable, it prints the memory adress where the variable is kept (& stands for adress off).